# I need to pass a php variable to DataTables.Editable sUpdateURL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

Hi I need to pass a variable called `$process_id` to the file `"config/update.php"` which is the file responsible for live table updating using DataTables.Editable.

This variable is an integer used to create a table (e.g. table1) so to update the specific table I need to have `UPDATE table$process_id SET...` and to be able to do that I need to pass  that variable to the script that updates the table.

Here's what I came up with after some research on the [Datatables.Editable Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/w/list):

DataTables initialisation and addition of makeEditable function:

```
$('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: "config/update.php",
    oUpdateParameters: { 
        "process_id": "<?php echo $process_id; ?>"
    }
});
```

And the `update.php` file

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'] ;
$value = $_REQUEST['value'] ;
$column = $_REQUEST['columnName'] ;
$columnPosition = $_REQUEST['columnPosition'] ;
$columnId = $_REQUEST['columnId'] ;
$rowId = $_REQUEST['rowId'] ;
$column_name = trim($column);

$process_id = $_REQUEST['process_id'];

include("config.php");

// mysql_query(" UPDATE $sTable SET $column = $value WHERE trl_id = $id ");
mysql_query("UPDATE tw_tg_sim_lines$process_id SET $column_name = '$value' WHERE trl_id = '$id'");

echo $id;

?>
```

I have already tried the different methods such as $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST. Nothing seems to work, so the problem is in the `oUpdateParameters`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new around here. Didn't realise it affected it that much. Sorted it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to make an ajax call to the php script

this worked for me in the past using jquery

```
var dataString = ('process_id='+ <?php echo $process_id; ?>);

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "config/update.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    });
```

refrenced here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This hasn't worked so far, here's the way I'm trying:

`().makeEditable({
sUpdateURL: "config/update.php",
      oUpdateParameters: {},
      ajaxoptions:{ 
       type: 'GET',
       url: "config/update.php",
       data: "process_id=<?php echo $process_id; ?>"
      }
     });`

Comment: Im not sure what .makeeditable is - but jQuery.ajax() is a proven way to make asynchronous requests to another URL

Comment: .makeEditable() is simply a function to enable my DataTable to be editable, which is part of a plugin for DataTables. I'm assuming I need to pass this parameter inside the makeEditable function.

Comment: Ok I reviewed the makeEditable documentation here - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/EditCell - I think you need to do some general debugging here - eg echo out some data to makesure different parts of the program are working - eg write a php page which echos each of your vars - then build a query

You need to isolate the issue!

Comment: I'm sure everything else is working, it is just the question of passing this variable. My UPDATE is working as it should if I give a fixed table name. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

I was completely over thinking the problem, I do apologize for this. However, if you are on the same boat as me, and can't see this clearly...

Here's what I've done to solve this:

```
$('#table').dataTables().makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: "config/update.php?process_id=<?php echo $process_id; ?>"
});
```

Which enables me to do the following on the update.php:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'] ;
$value = $_REQUEST['value'] ;
$column = $_REQUEST['columnName'] ;
$columnPosition = $_REQUEST['columnPosition'] ;
$columnId = $_REQUEST['columnId'] ;
$rowId = $_REQUEST['rowId'] ;
$column_name = trim($column);
$process_id = $_GET['process_id'];


mysql_query("UPDATE tw_tg_sim_lines$process_id SET $column_name = '$value' WHERE trl_id = '$id'");
```

This is super simple, I am indeed a little embarrassed. But here it is.

Sometimes the simple it's hard to see.

Thank you.